# Only border-bottom shadow effect on React-Native app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm struggling to create a shadow effect on the border bottom only, as per the below image, I don't want to use any library[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
```

Should add it just to one side only

Comment: It's for an React-Native app not ReactJS

Comment: @SaikatSaha you can use the shadow-offset: 5 10 property for react native